# How to redefine Z-Order in Qt Widget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have two Widget having separate implementation. They are ...
 MessageInboxUi
 ComposeMessageUi

Both will show in fullscreen.

In mainwindow I add both widget in following sequence

```
ComposeMessageUi* ptrEditor = new ComposeMessageUi(this); // these are inside 
MessageInboxUi * ptrInbox = new MessageInboxUi(this);     // MainWindow Constructor
```

so when I call show function of ComposeMessageUi while MessageInboxUi is displaying, it does no display (because it displaying behind MessageInboxUi).

How can I make ComposeMessageUi to front (I mean, how can I redefined their z-order)

Comment: lookat QStackedLayout. maybe it helps you: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qstackedlayout.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the ComposeMessageUi to block the mainwindow set the modal flag with

```
void setModal(true);
```

If your code is not derived from QDialog you eventually need to use

```
void setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
```

(see documentation for [alternative modality modes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum))

To just bring your window to the front you can use:

```
void QWidget::raise();
```